# Cannot run pyinstaller on windows with Python installed from Microsoft store

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pyinstaller

I tried running
`python -m PyInstaller`
and it gave me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "\\genie12.polymtl.ca\fondation\0001-Fondation\8000-Dossiers_Personnels\Rui Jie Li\nb annees don\venv\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "\\genie12.polymtl.ca\fondation\0001-fondation\8000-dossiers_personnels\rui jie li\nb annees don\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from PyInstaller import compat
  File "\\genie12.polymtl.ca\fondation\0001-fondation\8000-dossiers_personnels\rui jie li\nb annees don\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 166, in <module>
    is_ms_app_store = is_win and os.path.getsize(python_executable) == 0
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\genericpath.py", line 50, in getsize
    return os.stat(filename).st_size
OSError: [WinError 1920] The File Cannot Be Accessed By The System: 'C:\\Users\\[UserName]\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\python.exe'
```

Unfortunately I cannot install python from python.org since I do not have admin rights... Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: I believe the python from python.org comes with an install option to install just for you and does not require admin rights.

Comment: oh right, didn't see that... thanks!